# esp-zigbee-lib source files access

Tags: c, static-libraries, esp32, zigbee, espressif-idf

I'm struggling a bit to understand how Zigbee protocol works with the esp-zigbee-sdk's examples. I would like to access the C code of the libraries but it's static libraries and the the .h files are not giving my enough clue of what's going on.
Is there a repo with the source files of the esp-zigbee-lib or is it a private thing ?

I went through the libraries files and also search in the espressif's repositories on github.
I was expecting to find C files of the libraries to better understand how Zigbee works on my Espressif chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [esp-zigbee-sdk](https://github.com/espressif/esp-zigbee-sdk) README:

> The ZBOSS and Espressif Zigbee SDK is provided as pre-built library:
>
> - esp-zboss-lib: ZBOSS libraries for ESP32 series SoCs
> - esp-zigbee-lib: Espressif Zigbee SDK and APIs libraries

On many embedded platforms, you'll find some libraries (e.g., the Standard C Library) are provided a compiled binaries only.  This may happen for an internally developed library, or a third-party library that doesn't allow for source distribution.

The [ZBOSS Open Initiative](https://dsr-zoi.com) appears to be the latter of those two.  A third-party Zigbee library that chip vendors can license in binary form for their development kits.